# Como implementar JasperReports e iReport( ou Jaspersoft) em um sistema para relatórios?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jasper-reports, ireport, jaspersoft-studio

Estou com sistema com boa parte das funcionalidades prontas cadastradas e toda faze de rotas finalizada. agora irei criar um gerar relatório que o usuário ira fazer a requisição de oque ira querer gerar e a partir disso fazera a requisição no java (mvc) e gerara um pdf com as informação. Minha IDE e IntelliJ iDEA não e netbeans uso  framework Spring MVC.

E qual desses devo baixar [Site community.jaspersoft](http://community.jaspersoft.com/download)

Answer (score 1):

Fala cara! Beleza? Ambos são bibliotecas pra você gerar relatórios no java, Jaspersoft é apenas uma interface para você desenvolver os relatório, ainda mais neste caso que você esta usando uma IDE diferente. Caso usasse o NetBeans ele tem um plugin para o IReport, onde você iria confeccionar seus relatórios.
A biblioteca do Jasper permite você criar em Java mesmo seu relatório, o requisito seria o conhecimento de vetores e matrizes, pra você fazer alinhamentos e etc.
O conselho que posso te dar é pra você estudar estas bibliotecas e ver qual irá te atender melhor. Faz tempo que trabalhei com relatórios Jasper, mais estou a disposição para ajudar.

Comment: vou trabalhar com netbeans para fazer os relatórios, achei mais tutoriais com o msm, vc tem algum lugar onde posso começar a estudar as bibliotecas?

Comment: Cara, eu lembro que estudei por um material em video do Alura, não era muito a fundo mais ajudou.